# PrimeFaces Captcha not showing under Chrome

Tags: java, jsf, google-chrome, captcha, primefaces

My JSF web application uses PrimeFaces Captcha. It works properly under Firefox and IE, but it does not show under Chrome. I don't get any errors at page generation, but if I try to post the data with the invisible Captcha, the following error message is shown:

```
j_idt25:j_idt32: Validation Error: Value is not valid.
```

There is no element with id 'j_idt32' in the XHTML source code. I checked this with both browsers.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance! Daniel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following can be originally found in the PrimeFaces User Manual FAQ:

> **With facelets some components like charts do not work in Safari or Chrome but
>   thereʼs no problem with Firefox.**
>
> The common reason is the response
>   `mimeType` when using with PrimeFaces
>   with facelets. You need to make sure
>   `responseType` is `text/html`. With
>   facelets you can use the `<f:view
>   contentType=”text/html”>` to enforce
>   this setting.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This link shows a Captcha with JSF2.0 and Primefaces 3.0, maybe can help you:

http://www.patternizando.com.br/2011/04/catpcha-com-primefaces-3-0/